# Error: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID following Angular13 upgrade

Tags: angular, rxjs, ajv

I receive the following error while running my e2e tests after upgrading from Angular12 to Angular13. How do I start to track down the source of this error?

I can compile with 'ng build'.

```
 /opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/hostReportError.js:4
     setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
                              ^

 Error: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
     at Object.code (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/vocabularies/core/id.js:6:15)
     at keywordCode (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/validate/index.js:454:13)
     at /opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/validate/index.js:222:17
     at CodeGen.code (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/codegen/index.js:439:13)
     at CodeGen.block (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/codegen/index.js:568:18)
     at iterateKeywords (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/validate/index.js:219:9)
     at groupKeywords (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/validate/index.js:208:13)
     at /opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/validate/index.js:192:13
     at CodeGen.code (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/codegen/index.js:439:13)
     at CodeGen.block (/opt/wdio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/ajv/dist/compile/codegen/index.js:568:18)
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! fnm@0.0.0 e2e-docker: `ng e2e --configuration=docker`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the fnm@0.0.0 e2e-docker script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-11-09T19_07_21_544Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Ah. I think I know what this is... the package I use to build Angular e2e tests using wdio (https://github.com/migalons/angular-wdio-builder) is out of date and needs new @angular-devkit/architect and @angular-devkit/core packages

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself :)

I cloned the package https://github.com/migalons/angular-wdio-builder and upgraded the following packages:

```
"@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1300.1",
"@angular-devkit/core": "^13.0.1"
```

I published the package and updated my Angluar.json to use it and I don't get the error!

Comment: What's the address of your updated package?

Comment: I didn't publish it globally, just my own private repo.